# How can I achieve enableLocalDatastore feature in Windowsphone8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windowsphone 8.1 application where we are using Parse for data communication, my requirement is to store data for offline browsing .

I have seen, this kind of feature for Andriod and IOS devices, I have also looked into Parse and there was not any method for Windows device.

Here is a method for Android:

```
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

It might be possible there is not any option for Windows devices ,then how can we achieve the same with minimal efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Parse Local Datastore is not available on Windows Phone yet. You will have to use the caching included in [Parse Queries](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#performance-client-side-caching).

Comment: Actually I have gone through some blogs/articles which explain the same using sqlite , but didn't get how can we copy parse object to sqlite.
As they don't provide any method, how can we achieve this, if we create new helper method then we need to write all the queries for this which will be laborious work to do.

Comment: Well if you want to store the objects in your own database you'll have to enumerate all the keys of the PFObject to get their values. I know this is possible in iOS but you'll have to look at the documentation to figure out for Windows yourself.